# Use setViewController on a UIMoreNavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a very strange behavior in my app when I try to set controllers programmatically inside a `UINavigationController` that is embedded in a `UITabBarController`.

Basically, my app is a `UITabBarController`. Each of its tabs are `UINavigationControllers`. When I receive a push notification, I want to select a specific tab and set an array of `UIViewControllers`.

Here is my code (in the App Delegate):

```
UITabBarController *rootViewController = (UITabBarController*) [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

int idx = // find the tab position using rootViewController.viewControllers (the user can reorder them)
rootViewController.selectedIndex = idx;

UINavigationController *navController = childController.navigationController;
NSArray *ctrls = navController.viewControllers;
NSMutableArray *newCtrls = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ctrls];

// Add one or more controllers to the list
UIViewController *detailsController = ....;
[newCtrls addObject:detailsController]; 

// Set the new list
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
    [navController setViewControllers:newCtrls animated:YES];
}];
```

It works most of the time. For example, if my controllers are like this:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- More

  - E - F - G
  - H - I
  - J

When the current controller is A, B, C, D, E, G or I, it works fine.
If the current controller is E, H or J, the it shows a black square instead of my controller. It seems there is a confusion between the `UIMoreNavigationController` and my own `UINavigationController`, but I don't see where I could have done something wrong.

Has anyone had this kind of problem already?